# Utility to search file contents, open it, and go to relevant line

Tags: command-line-tool

I’m looking for a tool that given a search string and some set files, would search every one of them for said string, and if it finds it, open the file and go to that line.

Maybe this could be better explained with the following snippet

```
search() {
  for file in $(find . -type f); do
    contains=$(cat "${file}" | grep -n "$1")
    [[ -n "${contains}" ]] && echo "${file}"
  done
}
```

This is a simplified version — it will only print the filename of matching files and search every file in the current directory, but it works. We could extend it and go to the relevant line by putting something inside the conditional like

```
line=$(echo "${contains}" | sed -E 's/^(\d*):.*/\1/')
vim -c "${line}" "${file}"
```

But that has huge flaws, particularly when searching for code.

Is there a tool to accomplish this task?

Comment: **Vim**'s [plugin](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) for **Ack**, perhaps?

Comment: That fits the bill very well, yes. Thank you. Would you like to add it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the Vim plugin for [Ack](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/ack/ack) - [**ack.vim**](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim).

[image: ack.vim plugin searching for "package" in the source code of Ansible]

<sub>(The screencast was made with [**byzanz**](http://git.gnome.org/browse/byzanz/) using a [wrapper](https://askubuntu.com/a/201018/74792) from Ask Ubuntu, and optimized with [**gifsicle**](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/))</sub>